# How to access dynamic text within HTML icon tag with selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<span class="class name">16</span>
```

The "16" is dynamic and I don't know how to access it using Selenium Webdriver in java. I've tried By.xpath() and it didn't work but I feel like cssSelector would be more robust in this situation. could someone tell me how to access the 16. I'm writing a method to check the expected value to the given value. The 16 is part of an icon. I don't think that will make a difference because the cssSelector should still do the job.

Comment: I couldn't get you can you paste the real html element and why do want to find an element by it's text if it is changing

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String content = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class name").getText();
```

If there are multiple elements with the same class name you can use `find_elements_by_class_name` and iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "data-" tag to the span element: example `<span class="class name" data-hook="some.element.number">16</span>`
Then your locator would look like this --> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-hook='some.element.number']");